# Artifacts after render

Tags: mesh, uv-image-editor, artifacts

[image: Black lines after render]

I have taken over this project. I need to render this with a new UVMap/Shape however Im getting these lines appear.

Here is a partial of the UVMap/Shape. I believe the error is coming from location the bunched up faces on the UVMap/Shape.

[image: UVMap]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by dissolving some of the edges.